# Как переименовать название программы в android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Как переименовать название программы в android studio?
Есть готовый проект в android studio, но после разработки нужно изменить название и иконку. 
Иконку изменил в manifest, но с названием возникли проблемы.

Comment: Где-то уже такой вопрос был с подробной инструкцией. Поищите на форуме, там очень четко все обьясняли.

Comment: Посмотрите в /res/values/strings.xml строку с id app_name

Answer (score 4):

В /res/values/strings есть app_name -- его подтягивает манифест,  этот app_name и отображается под иконкой приложения. Меняй его на что хочешь

Answer (score 2):

В папке  `/res/values/` Вашего Android-проекта имеется файл `strings.xml`, вот его содержимое, которое необходимо:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Имя Приложения</string>
</resources>
```

В данном случае, по ключу `app_name` хранится название Вашего приложения. После его изменения, имя поменяется как в лаунчере, под иконкой приложения, так и в тулбаре, при открытии приложения.